# get uri segments from default controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-3

i have codeigniter setup to use "home" as the default controller which is to display homepage 
i tried to run the index function within home controller to collect the uri segments to determine whether or not to redirect or display home page but it seems to think that the uri segment is another controller mysite.com/segment1

```
function index(){
    $url1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
    if(!empty($url)){
        echo $url1;
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('home_page');
    }
}
```

Comment: try $url1 = $this->uri->segment(2);,  and  $url1 = $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: i tried that it didnt seem to work i tried changing the default controller to 'home/check_uri' and included a redirect but  it failed also

Comment: unfortunately it still throws up a 404 page that method is'nt exactly what i was hoping for was hoping to gather just the first segment to check

Comment: mysite.com/home/index/segment3

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$url1` as the segment then testing `if $url is empty` or not.
From your code, `$url` will always be empty.

Make sure you keep an eye on what you call your variables.

So what you have now...

```
function index(){
    $url1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
    if(!empty($url)){ // $url will always be empty as it's not defined.
        echo $url1;
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('home_page');
    }
}
```

What you should have...

```
function index(){
    $url = $this->uri->segment(1);
    if(!empty($url)){
        echo $url;
    }
    else{
        $this->load->view('home_page');
    }
}
```

Then it will do as you intended.

Comment: well spotted that typo it had taken me a minute to see the difference in code  however it still thinks my $this->uri->segment(1); is a controller which doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You can set default controller to home. Then to be able to read `$this->uri->segment(3);` you nead to pass thet uri via URL  mysite.com/controller/function/uri-segment(3). If you hav an Index function in home controller mysite.com and you want to pass a value of 11 via uri your url shuld look like this:

```
mysite.com/home/index/11
```

Comment: yes that does work but it was already something i tried  however when the user arrives at mysite.com they should see the homepage which is simple to implement but if they arrive at mysite.com/uri-segment i would like to run a query on the uri-segment before redirecting to another page to have the user  go to mysite.com/home/index/uri-segment makes the uri segment too long  i will find a similar example to what i am looking for

Comment: here is a link from tinyurl which goes to google.com tinyurl.com/1c2 see how the first segment is 1c2 this is what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

For this to work i had to change the routes to

```
$routes[('any')] =  "New_controller"; //created a new controller
```

in "New_controller" i could then define the first segment i want to get

```
   function index(){
    // define segments
    $url = $this->uri->segment(1);
     if(!empty($url)){
      echo $url;
    }
```

and of course my

```
$routes['default_controller'] = "home";


function index(){

// home controller
 $this->load->view('home_page');


}
```

Now when i go to mysite.com it takes me to the homepage or if i go to mysite.com/12345 it takes me to  the new controller page where i can run a query on the segment